# Python Pandas - Simulate Streaming to Kafka

Tags: python, pandas, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am trying to practice some Kafka producing / consuming and am trying to set up a simulated 'stream' of data. I have tried looping through with time.sleep(0.0000001) but it is too slow to catch the entries. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
offsets = acc_df.offset.unique()
time_start = time.time()
for x in offsets:
    while time.time() - time_start != x:
        if time.time() - time_start == x:
            send_df = acc_df[acc_df['offset'] == x].to_dict()
            for x in send_df:
                send_data('accelerations', x)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.0000001)
```

If I am going about this the wrong way, please let me know!! Basically, once the elapsed time has reached the offset, I want to dump those rows to my Kafka topic.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is some raw data that was requested instead of a picture

```
id  ride_id uuid    timestamp   offset  x   y   z   timelapse   filename
58682c5d48cad9d9e103431d773615bf    c9a2b46c9aa515b632eddc45c4868482    19b9aa10588646b3bf22c9b4865a7995    25:03.9 0.822061    -0.994  0.045   -0.036  FALSE   e2f795a7-6a7d-4500-b5d7-4569de996811.mov
58682c5d48cad9d9e103431d773615bf    c9a2b46c9aa515b632eddc45c4868482    19b9aa10588646b3bf22c9b4865a7995    25:03.9 0.842061    -0.998  0.046   -0.04   FALSE   e2f795a7-6a7d-4500-b5d7-4569de996811.mov
58682c5d48cad9d9e103431d773615bf    c9a2b46c9aa515b632eddc45c4868482    19b9aa10588646b3bf22c9b4865a7995    25:03.9 0.862061    -0.999  0.047   -0.036  FALSE   e2f795a7-6a7d-4500-b5d7-4569de996811.mov
58682c5d48cad9d9e103431d773615bf    c9a2b46c9aa515b632eddc45c4868482    19b9aa10588646b3bf22c9b4865a7995    25:03.9 0.882061    -0.999  0.045   -0.034  FALSE   e2f795a7-6a7d-4500-b5d7-4569de996811.mov
58682c5d48cad9d9e103431d773615bf    c9a2b46c9aa515b632eddc45c4868482    19b9aa10588646b3bf22c9b4865a7995    25:03.9 0.902061    -0.999  0.048   -0.033  FALSE   e2f795a7-6a7d-4500-b5d7-4569de996811.mov
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure I completely understand. Can you show the example data not as an image, and what you expect in Kafka? And how often?

Comment: What are you having trouble understanding? I have an offset column, with seconds listed. I want to 'dump' the data to kafka when the offset comes up in a timer to simulate streaming data. (e.g. when the timer hits 0.822061, send the row with an offset = 0.822061, when the timer hist 1.023061 send the row with an offset  = 1.023061)

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't see the image. Still, what do you mean "too slow"? The pandas lookup shouldn't be slow, but your kafka producer might not be flushing the buffer immediately to actually send to kafka

Comment: Overall, I think rather than look for `== x`, you want to query for all rows **between** the previous "clock tick" and the next one... A loop wont have micro/nano-second precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing with this example.

My computer outputs around 500 empty iterations before getting the first "offset", then about 15-20 loop iterations between each. Notice that I use `<` rather than `==` since timestamp subtraction will need rounded to have micro-second precision...

```
import time
# order doesn't matter... List will be iterated each time through while loop 
offsets = [0.822061, 0.842061, 0.862061, 0.882061, 0.902061]

time_start = time.time()
counter = 0  # for debugging
running = True
while running:
    to_send = [o for o in offsets if o < time.time() - time_start]
    if to_send == offsets:
        running = False
    print(f'{counter}:{to_send}')  # TODO: replace with Kafka producer
    time.sleep(1 / 1000)
    counter += 1
```

Example output

```
1:[]
...
657:[]
658:[]
659:[]
660:[]
661:[0.822061]
662:[0.822061]
663:[0.822061]
...
675:[0.822061]
676:[0.822061]
677:[0.822061, 0.842061]
678:[0.822061, 0.842061]
679:[0.822061, 0.842061]
...
692:[0.822061, 0.842061]
693:[0.822061, 0.842061, 0.862061]
694:[0.822061, 0.842061, 0.862061]
...
720:[0.822061, 0.842061, 0.862061, 0.882061]
721:[0.822061, 0.842061, 0.862061, 0.882061]
722:[0.822061, 0.842061, 0.862061, 0.882061]
723:[0.822061, 0.842061, 0.862061, 0.882061, 0.902061]
```

If you want to limit to data between two timestamps, you'll need to store the timestamp each time over the loop. For example, when you get to `0.822061`, pop and subtract that value from the remaining values in the list (e.g. `0.842061 - 0.822061 = 0.02`) and reset the start time. Then the loop is still `running` and after `0.02` seconds, you'll pop the next event as you did for the first event, and so on.

Couldn't make a good example of that without duplicating offset values, so deleting the elements from the list is another solution.

```
import time

offsets = [0.822061, 0.842061, 0.862061, 0.882061, 0.902061]

time_start = time.time()
to_send = []  # buffer data between time.time() calls
counter = 0  # for debugging
running = True
while running:
    if not offsets:
        running = False
        break

    to_send.clear()
    for i, o in enumerate(offsets):
        if o < time.time() - time_start:
            # build the buffer and remove from the main list
            to_send.append(o)
            del offsets[i]
    
    print(f'{counter}:{to_send}')  # TODO: replace with Kafka producer
    time.sleep(1 / 1000)
    counter += 1
```

Regarding Kafka itself - [Datagen source connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen/blob/master/README.md) can simulate streaming data loads